# ios unique number to register client in order to keep the purchase info

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

How should I keep the clients info, I need something unique . Event when they delete it and install the app again, I want to be sure if the machine is already registered or not.

a piece of code will be perfect

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to obtain a device specific ID anymore. This was removed in iOS7. You can use the vendor ID, however, this will change upon uninstalling your last app.
You can however store a flag or ID all by yourself in the keychain. If your app gets reinstalled, you will be able to read it again. The keychain does not get cleaned up if an application is removed from the device.

If you need to couple a client's account to some server account, I recommend you implement an authentication based on username and password. Then the users can also reinstall on another iOS device and keep on using their account.

[Vendor ID reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)